# How to open https URL with self-signed certificate from MS-excel?

Tags: https, certificate, excel-2010, windows-7-x64, self-signed

I have noticed that you cannot open url link from MS Excel 2010 Starter when it is https with untrusted (self-signed) certificate. I have company server which is used internally and when I want to cross link some document to a link on that server I cannot open that url. Instead, a dialog box appears with a text:

```
Unable to open https://my.company.server.com/resources/page?id=12345. Cannot locate Internet server or proxy server.
```

I have tried to find the solution, but it seems there is none. 
It is not possible for me to change that certificate. I just want to open it inside a browser. I am hoping there might be some way to get arround this (some policy change in registry, or something to do in MS Managment Console) -
I am using Windows 7 (SP1).

Comment: Can't you just trust the certificate?

Comment: No. It can't be done for this type of certificate (self-signed) and for this application (MS Excel)